# Can't get value from dynamically created control in dynamically created foter row in grid view

Tags: asp.net

I dynamically created footer row in row_created event and add dynamically created controls on button click which also dynamically created in footer I want to save data in linq table But dosen't works 
here is my code I really need help

```html
   protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                GridViewRow foter = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Insert);
                GridViewRow foter1 = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Insert);
                GridViewRow foter2 = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Insert);
                GridViewRow foter3 = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Insert);

                TableCell span = new TableCell();
                span.Attributes.Add("rowspan", "3");
                span.Attributes.Add("width", "180px");
                FileUpload f = new FileUpload();
                f.ID = "flupImage";
                f.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ShowpImagePreview(this);");
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ID = "ImgPrv";
                img.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
                img.Attributes.Add("Height", "60px");
                img.Attributes.Add("Width", "60px");
                span.Controls.Add(img);
                span.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                span.Controls.Add(f);
                span.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;

                TableCell celf = new TableCell();
                Label l1 = new Label();
                l1.Text = "ID   ";
                TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
                t1.ID = "id";
                celf.Controls.Add(l1);
                celf.Controls.Add(t1);
                celf.ColumnSpan = 4;
                celf.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

                TableCell celf2 = new TableCell();
                Label l2 = new Label();
                l2.Text = "naziv";
                TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
                t2.ID = "naziv";
                celf2.Controls.Add(l2);
                celf2.Controls.Add(t2);
                celf2.ColumnSpan = 3;
                celf2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

                TableCell celf3 = new TableCell();
                Label l3 = new Label();
                l3.Text = "opis";
                TextBox t3 = new TextBox();
                t3.ID = "opis";
                celf3.Controls.Add(l3);
                celf3.Controls.Add(t3);
                celf3.ColumnSpan = 4;
                celf3.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

                TableCell celf4 = new TableCell();
                Label l4 = new Label();
                l4.Text = "cena";
                TextBox t4 = new TextBox();
                t4.ID = "cena";
                celf4.Controls.Add(l4);
                celf4.Controls.Add(t4);
                celf4.ColumnSpan = 3;
                celf4.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

                TableCell celf5 = new TableCell();
                Label l6 = new Label();
                l6.Text = "kategorija";
                TextBox t6 = new TextBox();
                t6.ID = "kategorija";
                celf5.Controls.Add(l6);
                celf5.Controls.Add(t6);
                celf5.ColumnSpan = 7;
                celf5.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

                TableCell celf6 = new TableCell();
                Button Button1 = new Button();
                Button1.Text = "ubaci nov";
                celf6.Controls.Add(Button1);
                Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button1_Click);
                celf6.ColumnSpan = 7;
                celf6.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

                foter.Cells.Add(span);
                foter.Cells.Add(celf);
                foter.Cells.Add(celf2);
                foter1.Cells.Add(celf3);
                foter1.Cells.Add(celf4);
                foter2.Cells.Add(celf5);
                foter3.Cells.Add(celf6);
                GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(foter);
                GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(foter1);
                GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(foter2);
                GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(foter3);
            }
        }
```

```html
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
  Proizvodi video = new Proizvodi();
  FileUpload file = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("flupImage") as FileUpload);
                byte[] fileByte = file.FileBytes;
                Binary bin = new Binary(fileByte);
                video.slika = bin;
      
                string prID = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("id") as TextBox).Text;
                int proID = Convert.ToInt32(prID);
                video.proizvodID = proID;
            string naziv = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("naziv") as TextBox).Text;
            video.naziv = naziv;
            string opis = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("opis") as TextBox).Text;
            video.opis = opis;
            decimal cena=Convert.ToDecimal( (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("cena") as TextBox).Text);
            video.cena = cena;
            string katId = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("kategorija") as TextBox).Text;
            video.kategorijaID = Convert.ToInt32(katId);
            data.Proizvodis.InsertOnSubmit(video);
            data.SubmitChanges();
          
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

I try some solution from net but dosen't work.
please help

Comment: Button click doesn't fire ?

Comment: Button clicl fire but can't get value